# Caching image assets

Tags: react-native, expo

[Expo](http://expo.io/) has module called `Assets` that can be used to cache  images and fonts (not from web). Since I ejected my project from Expo, I wonder if I can achieve the same thing without using Expo (vanilla react native).

This is link to their documentation: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets.html

this is my code before I ejected my project:

```
import { Asset, Font } from 'expo'

export default function cacheAssetsAsync ({
  images = [],
  fonts = []
}) {
  return Promise.all([
    ...cacheImages(images),
    ...cacheFonts(fonts)
  ])
}

function cacheImages (images) {
  return images.map(image => Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync())
}

function cacheFonts (fonts) {
  return fonts.map(font => Font.loadAsync(font))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you may be interested in my higher order component module that adds performance related image caching and "permanent cache" functionality to the native <Image> component.

[React Native Image Cache HOC](https://github.com/billmalarky/react-native-image-cache-hoc)

Tl;DR Code Example:

```
import imageCacheHoc from 'react-native-image-cache-hoc';
const CacheableImage = imageCacheHoc(Image);

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <CacheableImage style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'https://i.redd.it/rc29s4bz61uz.png'}} />
        <CacheableImage style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'https://i.redd.it/hhhim0kc5swz.jpg'}} permanent={true} />
      </View>
  );
  }
}
```

The first image will be cached until the total local cache grows past 15 MB (by default) then cached images are deleted oldest first until total cache is below 15 MB again.

The second image will be stored to local disk permanently. People use this as a drop in replacement for shipping static image files with your app.

That should handle your requirement out of the box. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For external images you can use Image module's [`prefetch`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#prefetch) method.

**Example**

```
import { Image } from 'react-native';

Image.prefetch('https://some.path.image');
```

Answer (score -1):

I use [react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) for image caching (local and remote). Straight from the docs:

```
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image'

const YourImage = () =>
  <FastImage
    style={styles.image}
    source={{
      uri: 'https://unsplash.it/400/400?image=1',
      headers:{ Authorization: 'someAuthToken' },
      priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
    }}
    resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
  />
```

Comment: This package only caches for remote assets. The question relates to local assets. In that case this package reverts to standard Image component.